# How to extract attachment Blob data from Google Cloud SQL using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Apps Script to extract attachment blobs from Google Cloud SQL using `.getBlob()` property of `JdbcResultSet`. I need to attach this data to a Google Site page.

My problem is, I am not able to get through the attachment blob from cloud SQL. "`.getBlob()`" property returns "`Jdbc Blob`". Clubbing it with "`.getAppsScriptBlob()`" property return "`Blob`". When I try to attach the blob to a Google Site page, script flashes an error: `"Service error: JdbcBlob (line #, file "attachment")".`

Here is my code snippet:

```
while(sql_assetsExt_result.next()){
    var dbBlob = sql_assetsExt_result.getBlob(11).getAppsScriptBlob();
    var page = "myPageURL";
    var prodExist = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(page);
    if(prodExist){
      prodExist.addHostedAttachment(dbBlob, (sql_assetsExt_result.getString(12)));
    }
    Logger.log(dbBlob)
  }  
}
```

Can someone please help me on how to go about it? Thanks In Advance!

Comment: `JdbcBlob` looks like the output of `toString()`... if you what does `getBytes()` do you get the Service error again?